# Knife project on smooth cylinder resulting in streaks

Tags: objects, shaders

I've been having this problem where, when I `Knife Project` an ellipse shape onto a smooth cylinder, I have streaks on it like so:

[image: The streaks]

I have tried Edge Split and that fixes the problem, but it makes the mesh look really ugly (like it's flat). How would I go about solving this?

[image]

Comment: your topology is a bit messy, you should work with quads as much as possible, and perhaps use a Subsurface modifier to smooth it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I figured that if I Edge Splitted the edges at the back of the elliptical eyes, I could do away with the streaks since they were connecting the vertices of the eye's adjacent faces to the eye. Edge Split gives each adjacent face their own copy.